# How do I take part in an open FIDE tournament?

Tags: tournament

I currently live in Sudan and I would like to play in the Loyal Open Championship. Details of this tournament can be found [here](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_details.phtml?event=175562).

Apparently, there is no link to guide me through the registration process. Does the tournament accept random entries? And if so, how do I register, or ask for assistance on registration? I play in the FIDE Online Arena, but I am not rated, nor I ever played a FIDE tournament.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head to the [Youth and children Palace](http://chess-results.com/tnr313659.aspx?lan=1&wi=821&turdet=YES):

```
Loyal open
Organizer(s)    Kartoum Chess Federation
Federation  Sudan ( SUD )
Tournament director Khalid Osman
Chief Arbiter   Elatag,Khalid 12200409
Arbiter mohamed awad , Nazar Eltayeb
Time control    90 minutes, 30 sec
Location    Youth and children Palace
Rating calculation  Rating international
Date    2017/11/11 to 2017/11/17
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that this tournament has already started. Can I still enter? And how do I enter?

Comment: I didn't find a way to enter online.  I would just go to the tournament.  Many tournaments let you enter late and at least you can talk to the director to get info for future events.  Good luck!

Comment: If you don't have one yet, you will be asked to purchase a chess licence with a FIde-recognize chess federation, probably the Sudanese one.